# Removing a word from a variable in Applescript

Tags: applescript

I'm pretty newbie at Applescript and I can't work out how to remove a word from a variable if the word contains a “#” in it.

My script gets this error -> "Can’t make word into type integer." number -1700 from word to integer

Here's my script so far:

```
activate application "Grids"
delay 2
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "a" using command down
    delay 0.25
    keystroke "c" using command down
    delay 0.25
    set Description to the clipboard
    if any word in Description contains "#" then delete that word
    return Description
end tell
```

Any pointers?

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get text out of the clipboard, use `(clipboard as text)`. The clipboard can contain almost anything, even multiple objects, in multiple formats, so `as text` gives you a string to work with.

And watch out: 'Description' appears to be part of some existing appleScript 'terminology', at least on the Mac I have right here, so I am changing your identifier to `desc` here:

```
activate application "Grids"
delay 2
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "a" using command down
    delay 0.25
    keystroke "c" using command down
    delay 0.25
    set desc to the clipboard as text
end tell

set out to {}
set tids to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to " "

repeat with anItem in (text items of desc)
    set str to (anItem as string)
    if (str does not contain "#") then
        set end of out to str
    end if
end repeat

set outStr to out as string
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tids
return outStr
```

This code just **returns** the text you are looking for. It does not re-insert the groomed string, or do anything else interesting.

I assume you're going to tell System Events to paste it via cmd-v. (Remember to `set the clipboard to outStr` before you paste!)

`AppleScript's text item delimiters` allows the string to be split and reassembled using a space (or any other token you wish). For code hygiene reasons, it's wise practice to store it before changing it, then reset it to its original value afterwards, as shown here, otherwise odd things might happen in scripts which expect it to have the default value.

Comment: OP says _"if the word contains a `#` in it"_. It does not say _"if the word begins with `#`"_. Therefore the line that currently reads: `if (character 1 of str) is not "#" then` should be replaced with `if (str does not contain "#") then`

Comment: Thanks @RobC ! Correction made.

Comment: `AppleScript's text item delimiters` is only _global_ within the _scope_ of a current running _script_ and does not affect a separate standalone _script_ if running on its own. The _default value_ of `AppleScript's text item delimiters` is `{""}` and does not need to be saved to a _variable_ and restored if it wasn't first changed to begin with! If one does change `AppleScript's text item delimiters`, then one should reset it to the default after the applicable code runs that required the change, especially if one is going to run the same script multiple times without first recompiling it.

Comment: You also do not need to use `AppleScript's`, simply `text item delimiters`. In other words, and assuming the _default value_ is in play, only two _statements_ are required. The first to change the _delimiter_ and the second to reset it to the _default value_. E.g. `set text item delimiters to {" "}` and then: `set text item delimiters to {""}`

Comment: Yes, "...if it wasn't changed to being with" and "if it's running on its own" and "assuming..." - indeed, but the fact is, you **might not know** for sure, so for code hygiene reasons, I prefer not to assume, and store and reset. It's not hard and it can make code easier to refactor. Mentioning AppleScript as the parent of `text item delimiters` is perhaps an old habit dying hard (IIRC it was required in the old days). I've removed the mention of global scope now. But yeah, AppleScript is not for 'serious' programming, so quick-n-dirty is fine. If it works, it's good.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, this code worked perfectly! Thank you for helping me out with it! Did exactly what I wanted it to do. :)